# How to define a reflexive assocation in CodeFluent

Tags: codefluent

What is the proper way to define a reflexive assocation in code fluent.
Given this example, the design shows up correctly, but the generation would struggle with enclosed error message:

> Error   CF0036: Type for property 'OldEntityA' of entity 'Namespace.EntityA' must be a project entity if 'relationPropertyName' attribute is specified.

```
<cf:entity name="EntityA" namespace="Namespace" categoryPath="/Category">
<cf:property name="Id" key="true" collectionKey="false" />
<cf:property name="Url" collectionKey="false" />
<cf:property name="OldEntityA" typeName="Namespace.EntityA" relationPropertyName="Unspecified" collectionKey="false" />
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove the `relationPropertyName` attribute or set its value to a valid property name:

```
<cf:entity name="Category">
  <cf:property name="Id" key="true" />
  <cf:property name="Name" />
  <cf:property name="Parent" typeName="{0}.Category" relationPropertyName="Children" />
  <cf:property name="Children" typeName="{0}.CategoryCollection" relationPropertyName="Parent" />
</cf:entity>
```